# Copy differences between two dirs to a a new dir?

Tags: command-line, rsync, diff, mkdir

Edited version to a rushed question!

When I run diff on two directories ex: $ diff Linux1 Linux2

The output being $ Only in Linux2: COMPLETELYDIFFERENT22.txt

I want to the copy that file(not just the output) into a new directory, created in the same command.
I have seen this question many times, but none of the answers work!
I'm sure the answer is frustratingly simple, but I just cant seem to find it.

Comment: So you want to copy all files from either directory Linux1 or Linux2 which are different to their counterpart in the other directory, or which don't have a counterpart?

Comment: Please edit your question to be a bit clearer about what you want to achieve. Are you only interested in files which exist in Linux2, but not Linux1, or do you want to check whether the file contents have changed?

Comment: I want to copy the files that I find using diff, in the same command!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to compare files in two directories and copy the files with different contents to a third directory. I don't see a way to do that with just one command (unless you write your own script or function). But one of the strong points of the bash shell is that you can chain commands, using the output of one command as the input of the next.

First, you can use diff as usual:

```
diff -q dir1/ dir2/
```

That will give you an output along the lines of

```
Files dir1/file2.txt and dir2/file2.txt differ
Files dir1/file3.txt and dir2/file3.txt differ
```

Now, you need to extract the file paths from that output. You could use a number of commands to do that, `cut`, `grep`, `sed`, `awk` or others. I'll use `awk` in this example and extract the files from `dir2`:

```
diff -q dir1 dir2 | awk -n '{ print $4 }'
```

The output of this pipeline would be something like

```
dir2/file2.txt
dir2/file3.txt
```

That output can now be fed to `xargs` as follows:

```
diff -q dir1 dir2 | awk -n '{ print $4 }' | xargs -d '\n' -I {} cp {} target-dir/
```

Please note that this method only works when the differing files exist in both directories. If there's a file that only exists in one of the two directories, `diff`s output will be different, which will make cutting the filename out fail. Also, the file names must not contain any spaces, because that would trip up the cutting as well.

Comment: Brilliant thank you, I reached a similar answer eventually! (with help). Keyboard just about intact!!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old post but in case anyone else finds it there's a much simpler way that works for any OS:

Go to the source directory

Use a file renamer to add zzzzz to the beginning of all the files

Copy the files to the target directory skipping existing files

All the different files in the target directory will now start zzzzz...

Enjoy